# Is using a client which is pointed to by multiple servers bad design?

Tags: c++, client, destructor, shared-memory

I'm building a game engine, and I'm trying to reorganize a few things; namely the `EngineManager` which manages the main components of the engine (audio, video, keyboard/mouse IO, etc.).

The main implementation idea for this *clean up*, if you will, is to use the `EngineManager` as a client which will send data via event-handling (in SDL) to these various components, which will in turn send messages back. To avoid insanity, I have the following implementation:

**Config**

```
    class Config
    {
    public:

        Config( const EngineManager* engine, const Controls* controls );

        ~Config( void );

        //More functions

    private:

        Controls** mControls;

        EngineManager** mEngine;

        //More functions/class members

    };

    Config::Config( const EngineManager* engine, const Controls* controls )
        : mControls( controls ),
          mEngine( engine ),
          mIsInitialized( false )
    {
    }

    Config::~Config( void )
    {
        delete mControls;
        delete mEngine;
    }
```

**EngineManager**

```
class EngineManager
{

public:

    EngineManager( void );

    ~EngineManager( void );

    //More functions/class members

private:

    Controls* mControls;

    Config* mConfig;

   //More functions/class members

};

EngineManager::EngineManager( void )
    : mControls( new Controls( this ) ),
      mConfig( new Config( this, mControls ) ),
      mEvent( new SDL_Event )
{
    Init();
}

EngineManager::~EngineManager( void )
{
    delete mEvent;
    delete mConfig;
    delete mControls;
    delete mScreen;
}
```

I'd post controls, but it basically does the same thing as the config class - though without a reference to config.

Still, something tells me that a good implementation MAY be a function pointer of some sort...

Any ideas?

Comment: Whatever happened to using good ol Smart Pointers for RAII..

Comment: I could do that, but what about a function pointer which handles this kind of communication? It seems somewhat simpler.

Comment: How does the conversion from `const EngineManager*` to `EngineManager**` in the constructor of `Config` work (or the similar conversion with `Controls`)?

Comment: You have `Controls** mControls;` but then assign to that ` const Controls* controls`, which means pointer indirection error when you try to access `mControls`. Another big problem is that the `Config` destructor deletes pointer it does not "own". You delete `mControls` twice for example.

Comment: @Mankarse: I thought that  if you assign a pointer to a pointer, it must be just that: a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @Joachim: Thank you, I'll be sure to try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest design issue here is mutual dependency.  If you use client/server, the client should depend on the servers and not the other way around.

If clients need to know about updates in servers, you should use the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
If a reply on a message is needed and you don't want to use a synchronized message (sender waits until receiver has processed message), then you should pass a callback with your message and here is where the functor comes in as the functor can contain a sort of reference to your client, so the functor can send a message back.
If there are a limited amount of clients which don't change often, you can pass them to the server, but then you should use a callback interface implemented by your client.